# Claims for a role assigned to user not present in the produced JWT

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, roles, claims, duende-identity-server

I have a role *admin* assigned to a user. On that role, there's a claim *elevated*. When I sign in using authorization code flow and get the token, the *sub* field is correctly set. However, there's no sight of the role nor the claim for it.

I checked the `AspNetUserRoles` against the IDs for the user and the role. Those were set up correctly. What more can be the cause of this?

The claims for the client are present in the JWT too but nothing related to the user that just logged in.

Do I have to implement profile service and amend those manually? I expected the roles that the user is in to be added automatically, along with whatever claims that are reöated to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must investigate whether the claim is present in the ID token or from the UserInfo endpoint. you need to do this to isolate if it is an IdentityServer or client application issue.

In the client, you have things like claims transformation and claims mapping that you might need to set depending on what your actual need are.

For example, on AddOpenIDConnect, there is an option named options.MapInboundClaims that you can set to false.

You might also need to point out the name of the role and name claim as well using:

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
};
```

To add custom claims to the IdentityResource, then here is an example:

```
var employeeInfoScope = new IdentityResource()
{
    Name = "employee_info",
    DisplayName = "Employee information",
    Description = "Employee information including seniority and status...",
    Emphasize = true,
    Enabled = true,
    Required = true,
    ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
    UserClaims = new List<string>
    {
        "employment_start",
        "seniority",
        "contractor",
        "employee",
        "management",
        JwtClaimTypes.Role
    }
};
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Also, important:

The claims that go into the access token need to be separately mapped using the ApiScope and ApiResources. The IdentityResource only includes the claims in the ID-token.

For the ID-token, the client might also get the claims through the UserInfo endpoint. You can also call the Token Introspection endpoint using your access token to see what it knows about the user.

Comment: I've got me a JWT and called user info endpoint. It only returned *sub* with the correct GUID but nothing more. Not even the basic data as [suggested here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/endpoints/userinfo/), let alone any roles nor claims. Do I need to add more identity resources for that? A bit confused at the moment...

Comment: I also tried to add identity resources like *openid*, *profile*, *role* and *roles*. I got them correctly assigned to my client (otherwise I got an error about the scope being missing or not available for it). Still, nothing more than *sub* returned. No name, no email no nothing...

Comment: I do have a blog post about the identity server resource types here https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/

You also need to list what user claims should be presented in the IdentityToken and Access token , by tweaking the resource types in identityserver.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm now focusing on it after a while of absence. You say that I need to list which claims are supposed to be presented in the access token. How do I tweak those? I'm not sure if you refer to the profile service (and overriding it) or if there's some field I can set in a table of IDS. NB I'm not requesting any scope other than openid, so no audience is specified. That's not required, isn't it?

Comment: Its hard to tell from your question where you see the problem, are the claims not inside the ID or access token or does are the claims in the token not found in the User object? If the tokens lack the claims,  then check this Client setting in IdentityServer:
 
"AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken"

When requesting both an id token and access token, should the user claims always be added to the id token instead of requiring the client to use the userinfo endpoint. Default is false.

Comment: Also, which token is giving you a problem?

Comment: Access token. It simply refuses to get the claims (both from role and from the user) into the JWT. I noticed that the profile service will enter `IsActiveAsync()` (I'm assigning true to the flag) but it will never enter `GetProfileDataAsync()`.

Comment: The claims that goes into the access token needs to be separatly mapped using the ApiScope and ApiResources. The IdentityResource only includes the claims in the ID-token if I am not misstaken?

Comment: For the ID-token, the client might also get the claims through the UserInfo endpoint. You can also call the Token Introspection endpoint using your access token to see what it knows about the user.

Comment: Ah, yes, it was the issue I missed. Usually, I configure the API resources first, way before assigning any user claims or role claims, so it never stroke me that a claim must be present in the resource/scope that we access in order for it to be provided in the JWT. It makes sense. In fact, your blog states that too. I just never thought of that because it "just" worked. In my opinion, that relations should be stated more explicitly, bluntly and with emphasis. I'll post a self-answer to this but you get the cred, of course.   :)

Comment: added it to my answer, can you accept my answer? Also see, my linkedin message.